# xcodeでxcframeworkを作り方について

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, framework

xcodeでxcframeworkを作る際に後述のサイト参考にしましたが、xcframework内でAFNetworkingを追加したところ、ビルドの際にエラーとなります。

**xcframework での指定:**

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 4.0'
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
fatal error: 'AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h' file not found
```

podを使った追加のframeworkを使って、xcframeworkを作ることはできないのでしょうか

ご存知の方がおられましたら、ご教授よろしくお願いします。

**参考にしたサイト:**
[xcframeworkを作成する（第1回）](https://qiita.com/tfactory/items/34f9d88f014c47221617)

Answer (score 1):

`Framework`に`AFNetworking(.framework)`を追加すると、`framework`の中に`framework`を持つ`xcframwrok`が出来ませんか？

`xcframework`ということは複数のプラットフォームでの利用を考えておられるのだと思いますが`iOS`では`framewrok`を内蔵した`framework`を組み込むと審査がリジェクトされると聞いたことがあります。

`Cocoapods`をお使いのようですから、`podfile`に`afnetworking`を追加するのではなく、`podspec`で依存性(`dependencies`)に`afnetworking`を記述するのが正しいやり方のような気がします。